# Keras: could not broadcast input array from shape (14,1) into shape (14)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow on Windows 10. I'm trying to create a maschine learning model for the Adult dataset (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult).

First I am doing One Hot Encoding and then I'm trying to train my model but i get:
**"ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (14,1) into shape (14)"**

Even if I change the input_dim to something else than 14, I still get the same error with the same shapes.

What am I doing wrong?

```
df = pd.read_csv("adult_data.csv",header=None)
X = df.iloc[:,0:14]
Y = df.iloc[:,14]

encoder = LabelEncoder()
#X
for i in [1,3,5,6,7,8,9,13]:
   column = X[i]
   encoder.fit(column)
   encoded_C = encoder.transform(column)
   X[i] = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_C)

print(X.shape)
#Y
encoder.fit(Y)
en_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(en_Y)

#model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(21, input_dim=14, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))
#compile
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=
["accuracy"])

#train
model.fit(X,Y, epochs=50, batch_size=100)
score = model.evaluate(X,Y)
print("Accuracy: {}%".format(score[0]))
```

**FULL ERROR:**

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 36, in <module>
>     model.fit(X,Y, epochs=50, batch_size=100)
>   File "C:\Users\K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 960, in fit
>     validation_steps=validation_steps)
>   File "C:\Users\K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1574, in fit
>     batch_size=batch_size)
>   File "C:\Users\K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1407, in _standardize_user_data
>     exception_prefix='input')
>   File "C:\Users\K\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 128, in _standardize_input_data
>     arrays[i] = array
>  ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (14,1) into shape (14)
> ```

Comment: Which version of keras are you using? I tried your code with Keras 1.2.1, and it worked without any errors.

Comment: I was using 2.1.1 and updated to 2.1.2 and i now works. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Nice. Correction: I used latest version 2.1.2, not 1.2.1 in the above comment.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem for  a multiclass problem by using chain classifier and getting same error with predict method. I'm using updated version of keras and still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed the error by updating to Keras version 2.1.2.

Comment: you saved my day !

Comment: For the lazy `pip install keras --upgrade`